# How to set PATH in Knoppix?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I'm using knoppix 7.0.3 and trying to set the PATH environment variable. According to the official Ubuntu documentation, /etc/environment should be the preferred place for this. So I added these lines in the file:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"
GRAILS_HOME="/home/knoppix/grails"
PATH="${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${GRAILS_HOME}/bin"
```

But after rebooting the system, the file just reverted to the original one (I was using persistent storage).
Then after some Googling, I tried to edit ~/.profile like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"
export GRAILS_HOME="/home/knoppix/grails"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAILS_HOME/bin
```

This time, the first two variables got set (echoed in console), but the PATH didn't. It was still the default one when I echoed. What's wrong?

Comment: What happens if you write `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAILS_HOME/bin` directly in console and `echo $PATH` right after it? Do you see the value of `PATH` correctly?

Comment: @Shahbaz Yes, I can see the PATH value if just export it in the same console.

Comment: Ok now, close the console, and open another (`PATH` should be reset now). Try `source ~/.profile`. Do you get the value of `PATH` as you want it?

Comment: @Shahbaz Yes, I've tried it before. I can get it correctly.

Comment: @Shahbaz Actually I was thinking if there's some other settings override it, cause I can get the first two variable correctly. But I don't have a clue.

Comment: You are right, probably some other thing is setting `PATH`. Take a look at your `~/.bashrc`. I would normally put those stuff in the end of that file. Alternatively, you can write `source ~/.profile` at the bottom of `.bashrc` file. Try this, restart and see if it works. If so, I'll put it as an answer.

Comment: YES! That works! I didn't have a .bashrc file. But after I created it and added the lines as you said, it worked. That's quite strange. I think a non-existed file should not be the problem.

Comment: I put all of this together as an answer then. Don't forget to upvote/accept ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `PATH` is being overwritten during initialization of bash, after reading `.profile`.

From [the manpage of bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> ...
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

From your experience, it is apparent that if `.bashrc` doesn't exist, bash is trying to set `PATH` to a default value (I would appreciate if someone confirms this).

As we discussed in the comments on your question, adding the `export` commands to `.bashrc` (and thus creating the file) solves the problem. Alternatively, you can add

```
source ~/.profile
```

to the end of your `.bashrc` file for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `/etc/profile` on the following line:

```
PATH=".:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```